# It is possible to cast the homebrew spell "Breath of the Last Love" on myself if I have the "stunned" condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew, conditions

I have the homebrew spell "Breath of the last love".
I was given the status of "stunned" for 1 turn.
Can I remove the status of stunned using this spell, or can I use it again?
The spell states that I can remove the "stunned" status

I found it on this site https://dnd.su/homebrew/spells/3633-breath_of_the_last_love/

Casting time is a bonus action.

> An illusory copy of what or who you love appears next to you, indistinguishable from the reality that only you can see. This illusion calms you, you are removed from the effects of the frightened, dazed and fascinated states if you are fascinated by the opposite sex (even if the spell comes from him/her), and you also become immune to the spell Remembering a Past Love for the duration of the spell, completely freeing yourself from all its effects.

---

There was a translation issue from a foreign language.  From a comment:

> In general, the spell can remove the state of stun, the spell takes 3
> turns, that is, if it is applied before stunning, it will remove the
> effect of stunning, but if I am already in the "stunned" state, then I
> cannot apply this spell.

*Stunned* appears to be what *dazed* was initially interpreted as.

Comment: Please put the spell directly in question. It's a homebrew that can be edited or removed by the author at any time,

Comment: Oh, and the spell is not in English. English is the language of this site, so if the content you need evaluated is in another language, you should provide a translation.

Comment: although the spell states that I can remove the "stunned" status >> not in my online-translator... so you may want to put up the translation that you are askinbg about.

Comment: Dazed and fascinated are not conditions, but I imagine they are translated from the spell’s original language. We need to know which official 5e conditions they are supposed to be.

Comment: Also, welcome to the stack RUffinAD!  Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you have a moment, and feel free to peruse the [help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) center for more in-depth info about the site.

Comment: It might be useful to include whether your DM approved use of this spell, and if you discussed it with them.

Comment: thank you all for your help, I'm sorry that I couldn't edit the spell for a long time. In general, the spell can remove the state of stun, the spell takes 3 turns, that is, if it is applied before stunning, it will remove the effect of stunning, but if I am already in the "stunned" state, then I cannot apply this spell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You cannot take bonus actions while stunned

The condition Stunned says (among other things, p. 292 *PH*):

> A stunned creature is incapacitated (see the condition), can’t move, and can speak only falteringly.

And the condition Incapacitated (p. 290) says:

> An incapacitated creature can’t take actions or reactions.

In addition, the rules for bonus actions (p. 189 *PH*) state:

> anything that deprives you of your ability to take actions also prevents you from taking a bonus action.

So you cannot take an action, reaction, or bonus action while stunned.

Since casting a spell takes some kind of action (usually a normal action, sometimes a reaction or bonus action as indicated by the Casting Time line, in your case a bonus action), you cannot cast the spell while stunned.

Furthermore, the spell does not even mention that it would remove the Stunned condition. But even if it would, because the spell effect only happens once a spell is successfully cast, it would not work, as you cannot cast the spell in the first place while stunned.